# '__WebpackModuleApi' is not defined (no-undef)

Tags: typescript, svg, webpack

To reduce manual import icons I m implementing the direct "import one directory" feature.

I specified the type of `requireContext` as per the typeScript request.

Misror when I `git commit`

`error:'__WebpackModuleApi' is not defined (no-undef)`

How should I define this '__WebpackModuleApi'?

Here is my code:

```
components > Icon.vue
<script lang="ts">
// import icon1 from "@/assets/icons/money.svg";
// import icon2 from "@/assets/icons/labels.svg";
// import icon3 from "@/assets/icons/statistics.svg";

let importAll = (requireContext: __WebpackModuleApi.RequireContext) =>
  requireContext.keys().forEach(requireContext);
try {
  importAll(require.context("../assets/icons", true, /\.svg$/)); 
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCeuL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the .eslintrc.js file

```js
.eslintrc.js
rules: {
    'globals': {
      "__WebpackModuleApi": true
    },
},
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English.